# How do I tell if a VPN client's traffic is going through our network?

Tags: windows, vpn

We have a VPN accessible by a customer (we host a database and other stuff he uses via VPN). However, how do we tell if this person is browsing the internet through our network instead of his own's ?

The VPN is configured using Windows only (Windows server).

Answer (score 0):

Configure your firewall rules to not allow traffic other than what is required. Then you won't have to worry about what the customer does.

As far as auditing what the customer is doing? Well packet captures and netflow come to mind.

Comment: We don't want to block her but we would like to know if he uses our network to navigate, and see how much is that affecting us.

Comment: Sounds like you're setting up your customer, which is fishy. If you don't trust your customer, then fire them. Otherwise, just put in firewall rules to block traffic and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop Internet access from the VPN by disabling internet routing to the VPN.  "routing and remote access" on the windows server is where you would configure this .

Depending on your OS this url may help configure remote client activity logging .

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592691.aspx

Search terms like "enable remote gateway" , "enable Ip routing" for more help